# T=0 and T=1 and Get Response command relation?

Tags: javacard

I have a Java Card with an applet installed on it that returns the following response when I send `00 40 00 00` to it:

```
Connect successful.
Send: 00 40 00 00
Recv: 61 32
Time used: 15.000 ms

Send: 00 C0 00 00 32
Recv: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 30 31 32 90 00
Time used: 15.000 ms
```

The tool that I use (PyAPDUTool), have an option labeled "Auto Get Response". When I check this option, I don't need to send *Get Response* command (`00 c0 00 00 32`) anymore:

```
Send: 00 40 00 00
Recv: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 30 31 32 90 00
Time used: 15.000 ms
```

---

Okay. Now I want to have the above behavior on another Java Card. So I wrote the following program:

```
package testPrjPack;

import javacard.framework.*;

public class TestPrj extends Applet
{
    public static byte[] data = {(byte)0x01 ,(byte)0x02 ,(byte)0x03 ,(byte)0x04 ,(byte)0x05 ,(byte)0x06 ,(byte)0x07 ,(byte)0x08 ,(byte)0x09 ,(byte)0x0A ,(byte)0x0B ,(byte)0x0C ,(byte)0x0D ,(byte)0x0E ,(byte)0x0F ,(byte)0x10 ,(byte)0x11 ,(byte)0x12 ,(byte)0x13 ,(byte)0x14 ,(byte)0x15 ,(byte)0x16 ,(byte)0x17 ,(byte)0x18 ,(byte)0x19 ,(byte)0x1A ,(byte)0x1B ,(byte)0x1C ,(byte)0x1D ,(byte)0x1E ,(byte)0x1F ,(byte)0x20 ,(byte)0x21 ,(byte)0x22 ,(byte)0x23 ,(byte)0x24 ,(byte)0x25 ,(byte)0x26 ,(byte)0x27 ,(byte)0x28 ,(byte)0x29 ,(byte)0x2A ,(byte)0x2B ,(byte)0x2C ,(byte)0x2D ,(byte)0x2E ,(byte)0x2F ,(byte)0x30 ,(byte)0x31 ,(byte)0x32};

    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) 
    {
        new TestPrj().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
    }

    public void process(APDU apdu)
    {
        if (selectingApplet())
        {
            return;
        }

        byte[] buf = apdu.getBuffer();
        switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS])
        {
        case (byte)0x40:
            ISOException.throwIt((short)0x6132);            
            break;
        case (byte)0xC0:
            Util.arrayCopyNonAtomic(data,(short)0, buf, (short)0, (short)0x32);
            apdu.setOutgoingAndSend((short)0,(short)0x32);
            break;
        default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }

}
```

After installing the *.cap* file on the new Java Card, I have the following response for both *Auto Get Response* option checked and unchecked:

[image]

As you see above, the *Auto Get Response* doesn't work anymore and I need to send *Get Response* command manually.

I'm curious to know what is wrong with this tool or my program? Is the issue related to the communication protocol? (The first card working with `T=0` and the second one working with `T=1`).

Comment: PYapdu tool is an open source tool or its proprietary? A number of places I saw people use this tool. If this is open source, Could you share me the link to download it?

Comment: @Arjun I don't know if it is OpenSource or not, but it is free. You can download it [here](http://www.javacardos.com/JCIDE/downloads/JCKit.zip). After insalling you have a 30 days trial version to use. To expand it to 65535 days you only need to register in the website(And its free!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. T=1 just doesn't use `GET RESPONSE` at all, so there is no reason for Python to handle it automatically.

Important: note that Java Card *also* handles the `GET RESPONSE` automatically, so you should never have to implement it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you Mr Bodewes. So, you mean that the library that this tools used, is written in a way that it  sends a Get Response commands in respond of `61XX` automatically  only if the transmission protocol is `T=0` (And not for `T=1`)?

Comment: @Abraham I haven't validated it, but it seems the most reasonable explanation. It would be correct to implement it that way. T=0 is a byte oriented transport protocol that cannot handle both command and response data for the same APDU (command / response pair), hence GET RESPONSE.

Comment: Why the application should be aware of transmission protocol? Is not related to the reader driver and the card only? I mean, who determine the transmission protocol?(Reader and Card? or the Application?)

Comment: Depends, but usually it is chosen according to the information in the ATR. Some cards allow both; I presume that the PCSC layer will opt for T=1 if it has a choice but I clearly have to reread that part of the protocol.